# How to find the instance where a conversion error occurs?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to convert a string to a date:

```
SELECT
    DATE(date_string) AS my_date
FROM table
```

and it errors out: `Error converting text to date.`

Is there a way to see on which entry this is happening? In a programming language I may use a try except loop for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Try_Cast`to convert the string to Date. For which data it fails will return null. Then if you chose only rows with  `TRY_CAST(date_string AS DATE)` returning null you will get your answer.

```
SELECT date_string
FROM table
WHERE TRY_CAST(date_string AS DATE) IS NULL;
```

Alternate solution for amazon redshift:

```
SELECT date_string
FROM myTable
WHERE CASE
    WHEN date_string LIKE '%/%/%' THEN
        TO_DATE(date_string, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    WHEN date_string LIKE '%-%-%' THEN
        TO_DATE(date_string, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    ELSE NULL
    END IS  NULL;
```

Comment: Is that available in redshift? I get `TRY_CAST is not supported from character varying to date`

Comment: I don't follow what you mean with casting my_column to INTEGER. Can you reframe it in terms of date_string AS DATE? And wouldn't any inner expression of date_string AS DATE fail on certain rows?

Comment: @BigBoy1337 extremely sorry for the typo. I have updated my answer and tested it in amazon redshift it's working. The answer is self-explanatory.